# reading a column from excel and parsing into dictionary key value python

Tags: python, dictionary, delimiter

I have one of the columns in excel as following:

```
[0,[20,40,60],1,0]
```

I had read it through xlrd and pass it as string.

```
mycol=str(data[rownum][1]);
```

However, I would like to comma separate each item and parse into a dictionary key value such as

```
dict= {'Item1': '0', 'Item2': '[20,40,60]', 'Item3':'1', 'Item4': '0'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[0,[20,40,60],1,0]')
[0, [20, 40, 60], 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

extending the answer given by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

```
In [61]: import ast

In [62]: l  = ast.literal_eval('[0,[20,40,60],1,0]')

In [63]: l
Out[63]: [0, [20, 40, 60], 1, 0]

In [64]: d = dict([("Item%s"%x, y) for x, y in enumerate(l, 1)])

In [65]: d
Out[65]: {'Item1': 0, 'Item2': [20, 40, 60], 'Item3': 1, 'Item4': 0}
```

In case you are having proper values in keys instead of Item*

```
In [77]: l2 = ['Apple ', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Grape']

In [78]: d = dict(zip(l2, l))

In [79]: d
Out[79]: {'Apple ': 0, 'Banana': 1, 'Grape': 0, 'Orange': [20, 40, 60]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. But I realized what if it is not Item1, 2 and 3. It is {Apple:0, Orange:[20,40,60], Lemon:1, Grapes:0} ? For your information, I manually set another tuple such as head=('Apple','Orange','Lemon','Grapes')